# ng2-file-upload, new FileUpload() does not create new instance for an additional component, when looping with *ngFor

Tags: angular, constructor, singleton, ngfor, ng2-file-upload

I have multiple formats, which i loop over (with ngFor) to create new components. Every component has the ng2-file-upload implemented via the constructor (new FileUploader()).

However, if I add a new file and display it, it is also added/displayed on the uploader of the other components, which should not be the case.

What did is miss?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i8oc1r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll answer this one, on behalf of someone who helped me from an angular chat group. (many thanks!)

The problem seems to be that, although two distinct empty arrays are provided

```
<upload
  *ngFor = "let format of formats"
  [images] = "images ? images : []"
  [format] = format>
</upload>
```

or even better to see:

```
<upload
  [images] = "[]"
  [format] = "'A'">
</upload>

<upload
  [images] = "[]"
  [format] = "'B'">
</upload>
```

angular just references the second empty array, instead of creating a new one. maybe i lack the experience, but thats not intuitive at all.

the solution is, giving an empty array with different empty arrays inside...

```
<upload
  *ngFor = "let format of formats; let i = index;"
  [images] = "images[i]"
  [format] = format>
</upload>
```

asdasd

```
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  images = [[],[]];
  ...
}
```